# Usb serial port (com port 3) crashes when Arduino Nano has sensors or shield attached

Tags: arduino, usb, port

Can run simple programs on Arduino without any elese connected. However the minute I add any sensor (eg gas sensor) or module (eg ENC28J60). the usb serial port on device manger disapears.
Actually anything coonected to Vcc (5 v or 3.3V) and ground of the Arduino Nano Mega 328 causes this problem.
I tried changing borad to Mega 168 etc, but same issue.

Comment: Sounds like an electrical problem in how they are being connected or the amount of current they are drawing.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind:

1. Ground loops. Using a meter (DVM et al) check for a difference in potential between the ground of the USB bus and the ground of the Arduino. Check both AC and DC settings. You shouldn't see much more than millivolts, but if you do - it needs to be fixed.
2. If you're using one of those el-cheapo 2-prong wall-wart style power supplies, be aware that a lot of them have some serious ripple on them as they're not generally well filtered. Connecting the (-) negative terminal on the output of those to your USB bus can give you all kinds of fun. And not the kind you'd want. Adding a 0.01uF capacitor between Vcc and ground at the power supply output feed will help with filtering noise.
3. If the device is powered exclusively by the USB port, know that the 2.0 specification only provides for about 500ma (2.5W). If you have other USB devices hanging off the same bus, your current draw may overload and result in the bus shutting down that port.
4. Don't mix 3.3VDC components with 5.0VDC components. In other words, if you have a 3.3V bus, attaching the bus or driving something requiring 5.0VDC won't work. You need a converter to go between 3.3V powered devices and those running on 5.0V

Answer (score 0):

Many gas sensors require significant current - it sounds like you're running it off the USB port and I suspect that this is what is causing your crash.